# Regular expression for checking website url

Tags: php, regex

I need to check the web address, using regular expression.

If user type URL as

1. `www.test.com`
2. `http://www.test.com`
3. `https://www.test.com`

I have a regular expression like

```
/^(http\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(?:\/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*(?:\/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(?:\?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\=[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)?)?(?:\&[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\=[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*)$/
```

but it will only allow  the second option only. How can I modify the regular expression so, that it accepts  1st and 3rd option too?

Comment: See https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a pretty basic expression for testing domain names:

```
@^(http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/)?([a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]*\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]*$@i
```

Should match:

```
domain.com
www.domain.com
http://domain.com
https://domain.com
```

Comment: Note that this answer will not match upper case letters.

Comment: I added the small "i" at the end of the pattern a few minutes ago. That should fix it.

Comment: For .Net, it is (?i:(http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/)?([a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]*\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]*$)

Comment: This is matching http: //www.akgkguuiop which is a broken URL

Comment: @Johnykutty it does not check if the [tld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) is valid. `www.akgkguuiop` is a valid hostname, just that has a nonsense tld.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following program for validating the website URL.

It will be validating the following and any valid website URL.

1. www.test.com
2. http://www.test.com
3. https://www.test.com

```
    <?php
            $string_url="https://www.test.com";
            $reg_exp = "/^(http(s?):\/\/)?(www\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\_]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\s\.\/\?\%\#\&\=]*)?$/";
            if(preg_match($reg_exp, $string_url) == TRUE){
            echo "URL is valid format";
            }
            else{
            echo "URL is invalid format";
            }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pattern also:

```
(http(s)?://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ;,./?%&=]*)?
```

This will work for matching:

```
http://www.google.com
https://www.google.com
www.google.com
google.com
google.in
```

Simple pattern for matching.

Hope this will help someone!!!

Comment: Close, but fails with this test data "2020-10-27 18:00:10.128"

Comment: @BrendanKim, I am not sure about this test data. This simple regex will work for website url checking and looks like you are checking date string. So it will not work for this. Let me know if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `http://` optional and also the `s` in `https` optional as:

```
/^((?:http(?:s)?\:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)*.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(?:\/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*(?:\/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(?:\?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\=[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)?)?(?:\&[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\=[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*)$/
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pattern

`(https?:\/\/)?([\w\d]+\.)?[\w\d]+\.\w+\/?.+`

**This will work for matching:**

> www.demo.com
>
> http://foo.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead :

```
filter_var($your_variable, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
```

Comment: the parse_url() function is also useful in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Well my Regular Expression will with all type of URL.

```txt
^(http(s?):\/\/)?(www\.)?+([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\_]+)(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\s\.\/\?\%\#\&\=]*)?
```

[image: Tap to see the Proof with test cases passed]

Comment: Please check your regex! It must be valid for php. Use e.g. https://regex101.com/ .