# Regex for website

Tags: regex

I am using the below regex of validating the website URL.

```
^(http(s?):\/\/)?(www\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\_]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\s\.\/\?\%\#\&\=]*)?$
```

It work fine with the below website URL to match:

---

www.google.com

http://www.google.com/

https://www.google.com/

---

It also not math below URL

---

google.com

google.co

www.g@oogle.com

---

But it will fails to test the below URL:

www...google.com

http://www...google.com/

https://www...google.com/

Please give the suggestion for the same.
I have already go through the below stack overflow URL but answer is not useful for me.

[Regular expression for checking website url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490310/regular-expression-for-checking-website-url)

[What is a good regular expression to match a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)

Comment: What do you mean by "it will fails to test the below URL"?

Comment: Of all the _strings_ you posted as examples only `http://www.google.com/` and `https://www.google.com/` are actually valid URLs.

Comment: url validation is a complex topic. This guy created a nice comparison, check it out: https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Comment: Please put your question in this format: 1. The strings? that you have. 2. The pattern you want to match in the given strings?. 3. What have you tried.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the `...` you can use a negative lookahead

For example :

```
^(?!.*\.\.)(https?:\/\/)?www\.[\w.\-]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+(\/[\w.?%#&=\/\-]*)?$
```

The `(?!.*\.\.)` in that regex won't allow 2 dots in the string.